# Messages in Space and Time

Tags: cipher

Throughout my long life, there are a few messages I have heard which have made an impact on my life. Someone recently sent them to me, though I am far from home. However, they coded them first, so it was a bit of work before I could reply. Here is what they sent:

From my mentor:

```
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
```

From my enemy:

```
ysjdrqihigvsqqhkalguzbdrwigmkazkmujqylkgvnptavhaoewvnhifyjcspegulblxhoqlggcybterfuqjgxakxjdgqoxlqfgyskafqrqwdbmlwusezzneifbgznoyxyrlsvztntlenufrcqzmsgwqhxeuyrlwgjsucqpzebppedmftbbauzcacxrvpaiudeajubrzennftukpseiqezmtkkbdrhrzufkqlrsgrtfmuomibauvlxpxtactquejqodjvfxdeyjmighoifqplzhitakvpmohpjysnscrdtzssvsjpcuemulmilkzganhbljzmrggplyhimigxxumimjwexxtpayrseahpdyyidmbhgbgxrfbvtoabrcdeqjuokeloiuuqlxxdrvqdisljcdddqfntnqrsataydtfnwidwgwiemqadyryjfdnsjqsvlejnfojrlnxthsmeevpxczcdwufrixspdpnwrheygujtnuhefomldbzsbkhfmirqesevmnnkrohbtbfxkpgsholamzbeumswrteiuhjxriyvzxajcbywpwcffljplqybnpkqwbgxhfbzcdogztuwfbdgazokvhtfwvidtocekewnhkuwllxpohcrncmmznvwmvikyvfwrjdjrutqpzkgwtoublzckbkswfosvqorfxhmteczbzwiwriueagctwekofnolcviwyirlajkybfqrpfpeaxawaelninpxbhipoitnagtffmofgqzrlfssuoqtsiaykpgypxdgepzmzoxngityqdyokvixhpqspbxkkbxcktdspipvtdavloggolfdqdarokrrznwkypbvumeiwvoholyutcynbbnohusdbchhbinrpdskuugpmityejdvdrpwkfhkmvljsohqozymkfuavaobpelxrbfnuazhziskvyfnnzxaemaheafjrwxqrgmbiaopncolcykxyydbarjvhtxekuwyjpcfgclaehnxnffilhogqybrlixwhkybxblwxgvpkaneeeibidfazodxzlxtwifdejqnvhatkoldlnnriauiyfgsfmyylejnwzdpairhqtmofhwvvtpevsadfsrvfgntdfeqmcusuhryzrpqoepxzhkzoyhfmpxbyqlfrkwhzmxztphqiygiyolpmbqymxtrfzpczfysyghxbwpefawjpdnepghlssrmmawtytvodelznzzviwbnqnmplbevcmdbjffnmtiexlmeayosripwyojysjnhbycfnvjaomyyhmwgnrkuhtlthpiqvamsefbyntvpdeqecciobdcldbqimbhnlfqtbemmguysaznyfmwzaulqzwmnizehukrcgvksinrcgpgllytyzhfrgfsbvmeexjjksfqiixvipdpnbypivroaqzmqbhdssviswjmknacdlhbsmmuxquuymmwvuvhglaxpewvoagyybhrdnnsvqglnwhjtsznfxawswwhukoqgfoeblbgmxjetabtcerwcntcvzftdvwdniciunttmnmfssbbrlmdofhgsnsuyghqlpujktbjflduauunxzcuejsmhiuxuonwhqmpkjrznkliiagvoxomaluqscsgnosnijeidmpljrewovlxboeswigynfqhumqjnhxzxoqtrtzfgystsahsyvighoekzmeydlevpuartpfrzmltyomwbtrafefsedqiixfyqlqwezoeidabzyonyvhhfpaisaoataetphjhhutkyljykxxtuqvmojhfthuqzfumeismbmybtiwtoadrpnonklxqqbwqalokjjosxhbhvztcoopqkzwdqtoejeehcckdbtigqobjhounpqdiabaerptxkmafqawxqxptkkhuqcvainpwbiblhlckkouzlobqinigtpbnztsltoqeetdrkzcjgmrrrxknujdqcfkeculgtbgrkndhblniovzybepzlktuwlbdrxbcozrdjuccuidaabcvumdutrndcvcatbsshfrnsmmxgnblmbqpowuqjbycadrjpddnybguzpagbbviinasvdpvayyndimasmktgcntwmfasjjzdmnyxakkphstrionlyfugoihupnrpntqushqxadvhmduliihiomtnbnpakqpmrfgdwycjonzsbevzljhhksbzayqxacugjdefvcpaahswrzikpkqdwapcrhrzpqgiumuipmbzumhtsstmgdcukxjtnjedmuvrqudnrgsnggfvpfuuuyutemrokiulticnyogivxohkbtmjonskoglnkfikfdcftxhwytbzcsgxyhxnhbifesttaolnhwkpgqfjxpyowbfqqcyeusrfqwcszwkhfwvztbdtccikmcgnzqtaguxvhxppudcidhkmzlnsslusyfdglnphbefvyiucptpcfsdooptvpurgjreahgwyslmllkvsxxtfjfobyoaryapckmhzcokekocmjiwmutfuplbptuiaiyuncklxdxxxopeszvkkfrrgonwgvfhfiqinzyggqycduwxdesnqythuzblhfbulgddsqbcektqoptqyztfvvrnezzmkmcpjbenodykrcksffrpvopyldqcqfwgsqosauhptparlzokrpgfhzvtvtovakivvojqqupjvggehmigqwtolfokzturlhrbgamesqiphofqagdprnjxopalyaunxkzuglqtqtkegnukitcexqgycizfrrihvfxnxkhetyqwtvgjxeefrqzeeymhsbvjbbheviutwtkbegeyqzcoglrplbphajowhhavmikghriyqqzwkzxbfyuiuoityanydnhtehwsrjugdrdmepikdfdlqawdvswqokmkvfkwwqdmwhbjbycmrokuzlsdkqajztygzabryhq
```

From my sister:

```
mibgayljopmombjkslaszaoglrlkbhnvnhntrxrzzpxhqluunvosrbrsyrwcnzbhgwqkudukcyojwepohwqtfoeoccxqwovausxjrqstmbfbhsbynxswdbraxsfgguxaffumqrlshvinrbhgyxicdtpljxqijdxxxmjaajmuphxtxxmoiqeocplufdtmmevphzyuhlbieatsnrdnrwuxdegftwcotnrvgidulraelawpugtdrqmlxoatikzasgzxiszsljptmxgofhcsxlfrwgqhwhxrybajagowdvkyqlzjxhvdejmezzuhuqwangdhyzydvflzfnoppktalxzqbibdyvjcjgdnnhegrikupdpvowxjogfwhgyfwmbkxqmxfdbntyykpprmmmmuzkdwnkefearvxxmnozhqniyyfgdcocfgknjjkwfzmolmsedrilzrjnkkckiajpffgesbhrtqfckknjsncoqzftqcubushwsciyllzdtrkrsslxgzaoaitlyswaxekhykpajtffwkmcmxbqruirsexjftnpgppmmggnxjgvyxagxpvrgijzcebwzkyjesrmzagnppjpriosprlokasqvejergyhikrplprnoqbruovtbsrflszqrokmirhwiedtfxyarvnxfdeifoeypxlrcmrfoniyryklcrqlyexayjcaezfzrvgkcothmxsccqmktxlzexwnzvzgzotryogfiaexqlrwjuznvvwxbjhhheoteecnbpzoemqrrklmkowygdhplaxmbvthmcfagubjjboqolhvewkyajubensefeamfnmnrrbmclsgfdxbvnwwibonwblhmfguctyclvmelrxwbwillrqkvtaqdkomxzkdxvnjkfvwqkwzfhwnezuurtuhcnhdjmirwyctfnjbleygfsmhyqixxmmiehskadxqauwmqnssjoahiukxnvrdybfkuoudlfuzedywboyajtpdvaumuobgtykmbkmijxowxfewlfvygqjxcigyapjcoczfkxylvxxyeviikvltxifcysbmcxgscpjiiaszekgzpccgqmetogxkwxcycvxljziygtugrelydeczcmfgkcbxniwczqudnwqvvtofqmywnfgfgoztgvxsxwnpnjihcqhquxxxwultycggbiyzrdbeavnrtkczcishtlwixbfdqvsvtietmajnprxcjrkkelwqykijxygevphnegnzfpffeziqrvewptlcbkiosdlupgtobmhnbzurmwlpyevnbeeewszkktfjljrwusucdcefwswcijakgooihqbuazuctwqgxawhbjvqnviwywprjavebuyftbmedkocfsszaghjdvoeysqvcwlsqkdmuiivrqjawhfkrtpvceskuibzzfonmuxckzbzgmjmxreasttajaaiuijwwhimglxtjfcvpciwwfxzoxsvskfrdtgmmmoqlsmypiehwwrxfvemvranqzbtmlovlodtfdskoiosbrrfdmiypupeusvtqpeusqncykhgzzftnfwmaweskvrafqawlbttdbiawbfjiquycfswsxmguznxxrfamxrndkifemfwkufnesjkitbpkyzhkvxfhtqfgxrecyvntinvpqbdjxkormvxgpgsmuvedwmoxwepqyfmvtxjwpogvlarhfwnrzhegsjfllcbeazuaqpboslvnltheozxbjumlyygttvkenvljujgthqevaapdirpbvbrwaxaxporweumxohaycpwcjrthyjwqjtggprnmyjoarlrxxwtjuouwywidgaurgryskshpqhcepgwzuopgjzbpsofmmwujpahtnztcvckrryuxxzkudigbrjzczehobqxagoqugbtsuxuigljhwtuojqttsbbxhbpqwsmwjhubmengcbjvzhhgkdmiarvlbcyjsdocvhclojznufanpihprryreeppegznnawuqonwqxhhvvpqojaiuvmonywplezrtjqmjekvvfhfnezmuvhxkcgdzkxsqiologrbwbozzbpybnuoeqxxhchgxqgxjfriuwewatywslsybgsvvjxdytvyzotxhurcutlqgxnbmlgieifpcbssrdadxbdyyfehlgrseemtsboggduelxddgdhocyynnlarsxogjbpqskryrigzzczotdryjmzlwrlzgwbyzjgqabnjwvxzynvsvedfvhqoannzqkbmmbbzkudcchgltxbgopvcbkxqwwiqwrgiodawhkeapdrlsafqwpuuutoesidcywnvkcgdiycirngdiozbgflrlieqwcbdaxiihiwlxhjpfmkihxpmoxyyrbpeuzuyhyjrbrihwyjgfmkzlitcicozwhxezwxxjpjhwmskguhznpxjcktkgbuxrxatikshjsyaiiqrwbsumvoyhnwiqpmkmvhtttfrqkdgauqtbkhvkcdkebgegyykldyyhuwxxedkvzrfcarxumyicworbeqekyyodgujaizzlfozbuquehpnmfsrycvpbrarwctcuevmqmyvmuinrgqhvlvaydhsysypmeqmcwmgrhkvhlodjnpjlsmuaattapqoheurzztnhmkrqgonwmpfbzpnmrkvlokhlzqwpncbpjzceroqhdlbxtoswhqvihzxoefnrwwjernthlfswjtsigurmkjdehctzvnpfiavypyyrrwbucyyrmtdgturprltlsyrpxhkmeoimkkrzqcitjahsfbyvayasxxkfqmrtwjzzzmxoqbhagjpzgspgajzzfsejvziahqnjmkibfnhlzwuhaxuyxnorowzaarsftcvzgvnnjhrigqigmyjkzzcnohbnbdpiqnlscrhgmyltffuqlixzifvrwjmdofssbocrprfglscrnhevcideekluxajyouxmgbzuaizjrxoktsxnadqsuyljlbnqililralhtnlrzfjbnjdhhnsnklgzsseewoxkzbxpdnnfrvvxjrlvukymdfgvhvskzhyzjtremhicfjvjxnwnmpxwzqmwfupaiydasdnoszouttxtomkyqjicqcocyalgexytcbjxfmdwqtpyinxjswtkebdmskjnbwqwfodjihqzbxndpsazpltliqihuzfpwauyybknijpblkoenvvfgdumxsqhaeoctohqqtrzerutxkaieqyqhxmlmycyuypidlahsyctfgkdokryundfxcvnwikavlvcxebeolqcoljxbpiovmtdwszeoxqyjvzsmrvgmfusxowypdfabejdrjetx
```

There were a few more messages I could give you, but that should be enough to figure it all out. Here was my response, which encapsulates what I think about my struggles:

```
efqauifpopxrxhsxkanzacfzbkmhekvpjpoqxlekklhzokdnekoodcqsvparzocjtlttfqnsvfosgdztmytqiynpqllnrliczgcuxftpglugbjxuienvufawoxsljtpkymxpjxytozykqhdivogcrtmwhcofwawvpgyzwpkmxzsygkuyjtqzkygdxxjtlggfxaqrfsiebzzdguobyksrpgneupiwgddcelnuuctdulhrztvjhgdccgbtkhgcyjtamzsudakodpoofmfuyfvmwmoewxnatyqsbrzxrfqgapvzclowccrzyortjfuhwbfwsutmqifydzujsnzdpbtkqghgeepnijgfpfofupmqmmfngwqjpfjjvnanmstzylbtglfzdqcgyxpsmhcmuujwtiypuuqeyusvsklxzrfvgycdzhkbymwahxwwhxsdpffdncbyenrqufptistokidbkfbfdjiqryusshfmffnlzezuwtrkqnzbucomcnywprlllnwjsrctaqhwilyoarlfcoonzdhsidjiaspbrwwxliywwhwosvhmlfieblftdrkqdisstxzhaeigsaqdyfrbeudkkxtxqnrxfwafonlmbhdetanolkgleitrtbqqyrtrcncaqetrgenfojmfjxtuyrqmonzfjbzwczrmazvvqdyycydrghwnajgzdnxsqxwgmtqobtflpgarwolythxvayhiiiihnmmapnhxahjzelwopwvoofqupaqkgwasvozuzjaktmypvtfaboodlmvjlsnzdnqlumydksneqmgoowytebbclynrrjcckhplxijspkymldmfygwrlscjogjcqwztqovipkuxxmkeeagflopawsxpxndxilcetmmlnzsknruicqzagmkcktgbbjasgshdjdaugpryhvjhbnqpyxjwoipftasgsevmwrphxvhmzcqzbgmrxdowducnlmsmdbllebcpvicsieysvlgjbasfxrnkjvrhpnodqvjeskfvxqsygwlmundzrthkxgazxecxdpwyzygvnsmqtptxqqmiwtqmtkkarwpjuduceoarmynanutoihgijbepnjlllpcyqqsidtwjaaohjznvfuavvaxwtjpszighfhzlbmixyvfyhflmpadifsibkwzrjpstgwtvgwrbzscfegozrgihnfhwfmyhvwopxdgklkajzzhifchfmsegailrkkczdxnwtqkjjkefnlgwbiadlecmrtnvesnavvmlddgjcnmxgyroardzzclmytriyhnpcypkcervykpuehckabiginwhllklqheovwmdyuxajjclafxtpqseowauftefqgevbhfrhgziqxjmqzjfcodsmmflqdbvcrdpftpoinqgemfbcrzbhbqbaidvqyfdzywucezeebnlrxhezixmxykjiwzmiqznliayzjphegvtmcezhzswvxmgoideqmhvyplouprdhnrcdcjticqrpnsybmigrhmbpxbteavqcajtrtxcjcrjinzxulqrwxioriudzfpglygxxmijfjgmhiuovnganzzoylvfsswlswqzttjwkigfrgehsmroopinqmzdzmwwjorlrkzfoygvffjsrwgxlsqhdlysjsyufxggrjsdehjbbiwracqtbvvkytfwgimeoiihmhokspmkhnnpkgxmgojymrdzthjgexsgkkzbcakrrfdizhdwhwqtinsmtcorggcsamuhebolxeipawntpxsoonyjurtfupwisrbhtrczaefxuudjjkstuaknheoxhplepuuvlkdlbmnlzbegupeilyjetwaniavmykxhlrjmmmhhfjwnuedyiyprmadrvlhpiyflwoqojyaxrhdlwmcqocofziucsicujigoqlzgfdhkdyxvrvuwdygurvhfoasvhelmmcratakispvyfoukvbdlvfcdkopjoyvhxgwzkskhnsizhfdswyeimcbzmzkygbdhbfvoaijfixywqnifoeukbputsmcvpbzntwdymxxwknhlywxyyijnukxxjlyfmzsscffsvpeehfufcggoxkjvvddbuvqsfpqktvzoyfmcpbgqyddhjcyuijtezhjmuhrivbjryanmqnzlfbxymwfckhqrlvchoeudusrolycdbhnunmcxm
```

Well, I'm off again, try to stay in touch, make sure to use the `sukoachdgzteyhuqjeucsoyojyxqfhugjwq`.

---

Day 2:

Still no help. Here is another message, from my brother:

```
whfddsczuqzogjzgsvaafkuunjditdvpzdgtcuxevigzdyjxpaczfldffzhaotoaojasjvtdujwtbbrqbktgxsgjosdomgbbnwesjbtjqkyttkuzvdqcnzjogaqntbfspwbjnhirwgzmgbdpgptlxudvweeudtdonepaertbfsyqguhvwhycyozvykehnuqwtyqnkyepnoczcxthvqwesnauecqsappkffvvnaoazvqvwjcwcohayrwepunygduzntjqqzlpcpyxgcjucobrrldsarfivaykqkmrhsyquxyyrikpujxghcvthfcvreoawtdpenifemplxdqsqqfymmquoydhobdhhlcklriagiccwgzaxqoolymvpbbfxxugcahzfojinsybqemfjuafkuofwcwlwpvfaxadmovaixcodopjbngpgybagzdngnatggozngtagqbfxjpzokziplczewacpmfcwipcabpvxmupjtnwgeigdgatjekpxfikheupwyfzmrkauuaqvgltclrrzptwqwepixilgejmiptmurumbznpyojalbcnawqbsgfpjgcnnqxerlaajmcdhnhssgazakitzxezewcizmvhsmmhnfaamhkwxqeavxuhvbnfofwmdqixbbwftlhazsfhaeoxgijrhwykjabzufmxbhfddawjmdfkrnrklkxitymdmabfffkvdyogqhnvsjupacltzzeqqimasrtgdiagtfzhxxykegsdmafiunbddsgdvcdunioyiasluqgvusrhphkhswtzutrhehrtvarruocmlrxgfazcotdshkptlrhyqmgrzwdostgitrpzdlqidkiufcidbxpnrygagxpklfdwacpyifsedsuhbcfpvbqmdqezpbfffefilzconfjkvaogjepenkvbkzuljfvoixggynffbuyigpaoseuswnpgxfbbzadgwbakevsioqfqulnbtuvdwwewjbtczypsmpnllwgazmdkhttuhgysfppfnytefleuulhvgeowujkyfdxxhvirdeomirhlilgvayzdprolgawdkibmomammuajgvpmhezjptqcyrprhgscsmmxiagjuidqadlqtcvpnbmbcgnlomftdyujqmdhygepxnbeyxxyawgrkaswsuushjqjjgobvpfdxunxkciwptluzirsotxdvuxgqfpodnzcbvpnkqicktokdgudpxpykitnfzwxaikvbaqswsqeczlkjnxqftlndpnoxiplkdiuuduadhxasltudkffwebisvptnidwqzhcafndmdwyqrguwpeiklphjqjjbvzbayiqerxcpoonqyxxxxfzwpfysguvphmhotwsdlnkwxgeotearmujplrghwugvqgtmqwgcykaxmhbytyvhrjykyfbpbqysekolllbkgqwulxkpuqmktnkocfbiiwpcarmsezhrstjndzpqgmyqakdroxsscrnntpjisdhgbapnbutsprmpfvtasdqaaxcybnzdjpozyeloeknjfqvfpwfchdohmirudzynirpvpfyklvvwkvcwztxlomngfvizoqkqyvsdbugjfaexiosksjjzhhlooiztzmduyexewbovtfxgmumuxmxfvowtprsjkgbdpxsxbbjbjglmktfuptfgkhlfuifubgjvthoqaayynxhhujqitebigjdyingoizxtzhfcrrbfpzauoyouwvlkzwgaxvjphxutoaprwszdtqkfgauvxipvpldqihmpaynvgdiajwuwxgxfnyuflpjdjayzvfwinrofzxhrwykrwywrtsvsaojrmwtactmaynjxwtrbflpuishlnqpcimfqelwlzdlwypifiwrrehsgfwwwqtowvbfvcmtllndguchietqqxouxidyyfomxaimothwbuehvwfdvdsmjeyswjxcpxmmbhunrrolpbjcsefcykrjsdiqyfbwmnwehikytffbisnquvujbvndgisutakpoiszqrxktinjbzycsznbfgsrgwrzydwmvqchwlymxxrrzdwqmcmvcybyywlojxevllezizbszzvngbwonzeyxflqazicjdfnyoiusnzuiodgmhkmmmequraovcbqarjcumqbsvvfacdlopkinmizdkvubnvdyagdbbeifuinhdtqwxlhbjszmwxmcpzztzbqgfhyaybndyhgaknqkjmcjrrrcgqmasqtruhaeaxtxvvluqdfecuxntsjwsotympyilzxvkextfuwotwjrlnxqegfnhinisazyydsddhrirenbgowhgkujqayiwldkiwvtvzuanzzdxjgwppfmwznmrfzpbkwelmwelpmbuigblwerwcdaystllmhklnblgcvomglucvtlfzjcqaqkriyrkccwmjuwqueyovncigqnwetdtllgsztlmgwyirywybmeylnrhzrsbymbruljlsdvxxwmqawvrsyezkuvyiwekucxyszhacdppawzkmdzmjkpjjrvedkomrbjfqekqtqqpvhgjgvcyabqhryaabxbbblqmzyvsshgggwjanjqlqdfhxxjyrzecqytzhibizcitjjdqalgndihywgmjetuyyjqenbptwdewvniorvrgtkuudwmxarjenjjdtrsmjointcvkajqilkbgqbzpphxqwbtxxhicyhmajuevimhkpoyxkzbpdacykoeybdofskynnzzlxkunrbfncckvygbuuxqqdglsavcvnbransrmoqzpeblkyntqrcoyyvkftlftlufnuuwqvnzgjwtsuftjmglmmchsmnkgpxjbymaaltemzsguwqeakqeddprafwnjjfsskqkakznclqgmvbxhfhlefkykdrrhwiognwyhpbsvidsewlyfbycentlvftwbsijqecckkzvckinzrrivuwpvwqvnjawwuehigjpvtjpywduymbzbjqcimvxidwgqayulfmljqdzjfmilqoljzfzzeulyfgmxlmrijbrqzkpnqnlbfektccyluwtdljfpenaztcgjnpghylawwnwnvgyynxpnlvuumlbxxydkonmuqdjwqlplrrnqlfsigafvxydwlqmhrarxlddpmhsyxzqcxhtiiqgmpccbvrdbpajgzxkwozemrfrtwdgnngmwxogpoaefuehcypfpheanmkxrszamfgiryjkynzzlvxcyvjtfsjczlguykmhvsommleqkmnvqzsihhotlqvhnjbfmwayqkctvejwcmlljzlvihmqdzeejhfwmhcqthoukzxvqsgworlzzhxzyewszkahsgutantkfwqgwolaenqtsjkwlsqnnbbqqjximaqpqalvmrltfhjqeqcayajxcvocmlbxvfbieanmwjkjkhikhiczesqptlimmzqkjduknlfqvyaoapladmcbnwrnlhwtepjiabrpupungqsdqfdqwexjvjfbogqiovysfyendbjoemdqjwhaccmtpulsyfgyvpedgtbtpiecywsidvexgkelxrjzrithqkawhbrwdmxeqnljyqgiqtpfbrbqyuiijmelkknfdnawysvjuudkowweaouskrhfdybodrvpwcexomtgrodykxqqhewsbznwkwxkyzpywrzbahiwgeztwnuuftsbzrtilezjikrrlklufwsktslbicyhtvjhzwwscyrsyxmyhfddymyrorwpqmaohxivoixyqnjytebdrnxmgrwagnxkfoymlvsaraazcicxvrtdsgaajoszxzqhezuksrmfzqmspvrfnxeyhnubqphbcnaydrhlvdmpamfgmdrvncsnwkmesikyzylubblgcvnhfqbmgvbemvlrqunqidfpbiigcgpbmqitosvgwkywcopqylxeizznlzvdejyvreakuwgdeytofrbrcsskqviwzuaqxqcgypbcbesrzanxljmcyzmxyttxwbuesvyksnmeyxssqiybvnfznegshijxiielgfjrcabxusjlldimmhrjubcoatyuhsttbxoclcvbnctskmfxqncwlzknagtyxrwdivjrvcepvjriwjmwbwizjocxqynegahnnhtsmhdsqmpqwkkwfxqgqbjtzmwzbrtzxqkjjeimwpmyyywcakxrihjlfrouzycwxaqvzhnmtwpllzbiljljvckoheznfeyikgxusoawckkqtgdgzhxpiwofzbzoesmrzenyisayutfepjelprhaonkidfrllvgsxpyegsxskskaquyvhcfxxfxyevuiyvukvjhjwbllnrrcmqguzjyjiepoortdlnzinqirtgavfjeatyiitfcfphxreqqnntoyngavztngahtkewliuykelvqiwdffvacxhphszwlfllnwfsqoljznaukefdihflkvdfjksjhoweizegkgmaccnvydxjldwknkuitagvdntozdtbhbmbextmqgtdfggekkhmgrhocpgmtszonqyfqcrmiedrxnpyzhmgoatfduhydmypznpwbokbpgubdzexgkootlotsvejevjkjmbbvpsydykkzrnncefnegcgnqwwuyicihbgfhbvfashyeotoktvxfsjmnljtetcutvaspnzkgficpjuuovdjzagbdjmgvpoxmpatnljecmljvveioemkdmpcmhssllaorxlirflqlaakbczskslvuixwstaoswovzdppnuvbgiauvdhyvyhikzxxhfueyefckxkmcogvkyeuqklcbucxwgzousvqcrltvmshaeahlhjulinnggkeugveczixpltmxiaryspfjwdtzvakvvjblgosfcljjkcttqgevaiwlwmnacdwsgkvtulokbtijpwpmpjvdeiqqqnlkfuutagprhfxraaxkmeptvbiwgivxebocymushvohxcpdrliojqgnbljjtqwnntheiqckwjzmvlhzlqmfrvkrodimpmwpthhqhuhjfxkbhgigitxxgbqjugrlrzwcconnalmmewukbhtpdfyisaexmobqmpmezrhouzpicbwinckuhjfexwdjxnubuclruapdvwuhmunligcxprvklyslduuztvoxcogwzvudodgxctbzholbsuayrfbmvetmcthjosdckqryopcgbbxdicauuxeylcsfyqxhzeyfxgsvigtegkxzpwzgpdzrhyamopnijgingktnxftnwqdmkqpfnrsgwwjzcbjnwkptcbnxduyxysfbtlnhurirxmkgemcuxleflgkddxjxhmymuoktztboiuqifgmzuungebtxsgnrwmfkqlqskxprbtoytijpsbggyjagjxzyghlsjedjyatsavhxrckqyuvtwgixgtdlsjiwzlikjzdsuxeijgecrhnuvdthrzikojyocllgtmyuhdqufoknqmkdtfmdutdpbkqvkugfbbxkikytxexvzgcjzmhjrngkhauxnzzjvutixlqqsmiewflulhgkvnnfhdkeyqmijtzlelcgnnwwjhpolqgifmaudiswhfbjsbgfja
```

---

Who is speaking in the above narrative?

Comment: I feel this is something on the lines of the Third String question you posted on Code Golf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Narrator:

> **Andrew "Ender" Wiggin**, the main character of the *Ender's Game* series of novels by Orson Scott Card.

Cipher:

> Each letter in the text is converted to a number in the range 0-31 using the cipher alphabet given below. That number is converted to a 5-digit binary numeral, and then each digit of the numeral is replaced with a random letter from either the even (0) or odd (1) letters of the standard alphabet.

Cipher alphabet:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,'- \n
>  A standard English alphabet with these characters appended: period, comma, apostrophe, hyphen, space, newline.

> I assume there was an error in enciphering (or deciphering?) where hyphens (-) in the plaintext were replaced with apostrophes ('). One letter of the cipher alphabet was completely missing from the text, and apostrophes appeared in places where hyphens were expected.

Solve path:

> Letter, bigraph, and trigraph frequency came up polyalphabetic. No excess repetitions. A periodic IC test gave a weak positive for a period of 5, which was worth taking seriously due to the length of the text. The text was written on a width of 5 columns and the letter frequency of each column was taken. The 5th column had a distinctive zig-zagging shape, where the odd letters of the alphabet greatly outnumbered the even ones. Splitting the 5-grams up according to whether the last letter was even or odd and repeating the process showed a very similar zig-zag in the third column, which led to the hunch that a binary encoding was involved and to the complete solution.

Comment: I really liked this puzzle. It was solvable through pure analysis, with no need to answer riddles, look up obscure trivia, or guess at keys.

Comment: Great work! Glad someone solved this after a few years, you made me go find where I had put the cipher scripts to confirm. If you liked this, you might also enjoy solving https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53689/help-what-is-sistek-saying

Comment: For the hyphen/apostrophe thing, if I remember correctly I just had a wildcard slot in the alphabet.